# A Database DateTime Value Conflict

Tags: sql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have hourly price data for 10 years.  Meaning, 24 prices for each day.

The problem is, the price is from the previous hour of trading.  So, the source of my data has listed a 24th hour for each day, and there is no 0 hour.

```
  Example (for further clarity):   
  The records for a day start at: 07/20/2010 01:00:00 
  The records for a day end at: 07/20/2010 24:00:00
```

This conflicts with the way my Rails Apps PostgreSQL DB wants to save DateTime value.  When I imported this data from CSV into my DB and saved the dates into a DateTime column, it changed all of the 24:00:00 into 00:00:00 of the following day.  This throws off the accuracy of my various end-uses.

Is there anyway I can modify my Postgres DB's behavior to not do this?  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you show the code that is doing the import?

Comment: A CSV file is being imported via a PostgreSQL GUI named Navicat for PostgreSQL.  The CSV records being at 01:00:00 and end at 24:00:00 appropriately.  Could I write my own import code to get around this?

Comment: Is the database empty when you start the import, or do you at least have a start time that you can do some post processing from?

Comment: It is empty...  I can edit the CSV.  I will just have to rewrite the code that auto saves future data.

Comment: +1 interesting question btw

Comment: I appreciate the help hafichuk.  Thank you.  Have a good one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always subtract an hour after you perform the import.

I don't know your database schema so to do this in a general fashion you'd have to execute this SQL on each column that has a date.

```
UPDATE table SET date_field = date_field - INTERVAL '1 hour'
```